# How to trigger a Wi-Fi access point signal information update

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dbus

I've found many sources which describe how to get the signal strength of the current (connected to) or other Wi-Fi access points, but in most of them, the tools just show the last available information or wait until polling is executed automatically by some system service.

Which tools, or more precisely via which programming API I would be able to trigger a manual forced polling of the information of the required Wi-Fi access point. I require this functionality for implementing a positioning system that is based on Wi-Fi access point signals, thus I need accurate and up-to-date information.

Using Ubuntu 18.04 on an Nvidia Jetson Nano.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David, it's an Nvidia Jetson Nano on Ubuntu 18.04 (arm64).

Comment: have a look to `wavemon` https://github.com/uoaerg/wavemon/